# Failed to start Ubuntu Live CD Installer on HP

Tags: boot

I am trying to start the Ubuntu Live CD Installer (22.04) on my HP Spectre laptop. Unfortunately it always ends without the well known screen where you can normally decide if you want to 1) start the live cd system or 2) begin with the installation. Instead it always says: failed to start Ubuntu Live CD Installer on the command line. I was also trying older versions but with the same result. So it looks like some incompatibility or something really strange.

The system is using a hybrid graphical approach meaning that there is the internal Intel UHD Graphics 630 chip available (coming with the CPU) and a separate NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 Ti.

As a workaround I already tried to use the save graphics mode, some other boot parameters noapci or nomodeset... but also with no success. Finally I tried to do the same while in the BIOS Secure Boot is disabled and Legacy BIOS mode enabled.

There is no clear message why it is not booting up.

Can someone help me to do a little bit more troubleshooting, find the root cause and may get Ubuntu Live CD up and running?

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Are you using optical media (it would have to DVD, not CD anyway)? If so use a properly made USB stick instead and make sure the ISO isn't corrupt. Yes, disabling Secure Boot is convenient (but not necessary) but forcing Legacy/"BIOS" mode in 2022 is ridiculous. No, disable that mode and/or assure you're booting in UEFI mode, period.

Comment: Thank you for you quick reply. Yes I am using a DVD and not an CD. All right, understood. So will disable Legacy BIOS and re-enable the Secure Boot. Thank you for the advice regarding the USB stick. I will give it a try. But what do you mean with a properly made USB stick? Are the options for HP notebooks with other drivers? Thank you

Comment: 1. A properly made live/instalation USB starts with a good ISO and then with a proper tool. If doing it from Windows Balena Etcher or Rufus (with UEFI/GPT settings). 2. Optical media should be used because is excruciatingly slow when it works and it doesn't with the original 22.04 ISO. 3. In your case it's very convenient to disable Secure Boot as it saves one additional step to have the Nvidia graphics working. 4. During the Ubuntu install make sure to enable the option to install 3rd party drivers, codecs, etc. as that will automatically install drivers for your Nvidia. (...)

Comment: Lastly, it should boot the live session normally but if it doesn't then use the "safe graphics" option.

Comment: Thank you for the clear statements. I will give it a try without having Secure Boot disabled using an USB stick with Ubuntu. Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Booting the ISO using an USB stick was working. I have used the latest release 22.04.1 and it worked without using the safe "graphics mode". Awesome.

Comment: Do you have an additional advice what driver I should use when I want to connect two external monitors which are connected to my docking station with USB-C? Do you think it works with the driver provided by Ubuntu in 3rp party mode?

Comment: Yes, it should work provided the USB-C connection is using the standard video output feature. Such feature isn't available in all USB-C ports. Some docking stations rely on a DisplayLink chipset that is supported in Ubuntu but requires another drivers.

Comment: Thank you for the advice regarding the docking station topic. I will let you know if I was able to manage the configuration once I completed the Ubuntu installation. Until now I am still using the Live CD image. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I was unable to install 22.04.1 with either DVD or with thumb drive. The ISO's sha256sum checked OK, and I compared the thumb drive byte-for-byte with the ISO using `cmp` on a Linux machine.

I also tried it with and without safe graphics (can't recall exactly what that option was called).  I tried it on two dissimilar computers (both with onboard graphics).  Always the same result -- it boots into live session, but won't install after that.

What I finally had to do was install Ubuntu Server (which went without a hitch), then I installed `tasksel`, then I used `tasksel` to install LXQT, then rebooted. That worked, and it pulled in most of the applications I need.

BTW: I did try installing the Gnome task, but something went wrong and Firefox wouldn't start. Also the mouse cursor was just a white square. It's probably not hard to fix these things, but I'm happy with LXQT so I'm calling it done.